# Passing table name and column name dynamically to PL/SQL Stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, execute-immediate, dbms-output

I am trying to pass table name and column name to a stored procedure in oracle , but it gives me following error: `table or view does not exist`

Below is the code:

```
create or replace procedure jz_dynamic_sql_statement
    (p_table_name    in varchar2,
     p_col1_name     in varchar2,
     p_check_result  out integer)

  as

    v_error_cd          est_runtime_error_log.error_cd%type;
    v_error_msg         est_runtime_error_log.error_msg%type;
    v_sql               varchar2(1024);
    v_result            number(10);

  begin
    v_result    := 0;
    v_sql       := 'select  count(*)  from ' || p_table_name ||' WHERE COLUMNNAME=' || p_col1_name;


    execute immediate v_sql into v_result;
    p_check_result := v_result;

  end;
```

Comment: What is confusing about this?  The table doesn't exist.

Comment: I mean i have the table already.

Comment: The where clause does not make sense unless you were trying to obfuscate your DB column names on the post.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - table could exist but the caller vs definer permissions could be interfering with the visibility of the table.

Comment: Well, i need to filter it and i m going to use this idea for other purposes such as update statement

Comment: I am runnnig it under same schema name so it should find the table i guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the error coming back says the table does not exist then that means the table you pass in does not exist or the user that the procedure runs under cannot access it.

You could add a dbms_output.put_line statement to display the query that you are building and then try running it yourself, before you attempt the execute immediate. Then you know what errors you need to fix.

```
dbms_output.put_line('query : '||v_sql);
```

Be sure to turn on dbms_output.

Also, from what it looks like you are trying to do, you will need to pass the column name AND column value. Unless the tables you are querying will ALWAYS have the column name "COLUMNNAME".

Try this:

```
v_sql       := 'select  count(*)  from ' || p_table_name ||' WHERE COLUMNNAME=''' || p_col1_name|| '''';
```

Comment: this one runs well    v_sql  := 'select  count(*)  from ' || p_table_name ||''; but when  i inlcude where clasue with the column name then it gives following error above.

Comment: does the table you trying to query have the column "COLUMNNAME"?

Comment: Yes. it has a column called 'COLUMNNAME'

Comment: i just noticed you are not surrounding the COLUMNNAME value you passing in in single qutotes. I'll update my answer with more info.

Comment: Better use `'select  count(*)  from ' || p_table_name ||' WHERE COLUMNNAME= :val'; execute immediate v_sql into v_result using p_col1_name;`